# Lost connection to MySQL server during query mysqlclient-dev multithreading

Tags: mysql, c, multithreading, database-connection

Folks, I had another issue now regarding to `libmysqlclient-dev api`

Here the story:

I created about 10 threads which will do SQL query in every 2 seconds, and loop,
in math you could say 10 query in 2 seconds **in the same time**, and it ended itself with MySQL error message **lost connection during SQL query**

Questions:

1. in these case, is my algorithm will always cause MySQL server lost connection ?
2. if so, will these issue appear if I use another db (say Oracle, Postgre, etc), or result will same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well everything is now run better once

- the `MYSQL*` is protected by posix-mutex https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/#MutexLocking
- the code compiiled with `mysql_config --libs_r` parameter

thats for now, any addition ?

Answer (score 0):

1. What are you doing in the thread that loses the connection, and what are the other threads doing at the same time?
2. It depends. Consider your question the equivalent of "my car makes a funny noise when I drive down Street X. Should I get a new car?". If the noise is due to you falling into a pothole, changing cars won't make any difference.

Comment: 1. let say "select id from user" for every thread, because they're alike, but the problem appear when another function try to query sql while the threads still in looping